# Adding security to a wiki

Tags: mysql, authentication, wiki

My company wants to use a wiki for training, to try and encourage a team learning and teaching approach.  It was easy enough to set up the wiki, but I am trying to find the best way to require a username/password that calls upon an existing users mysql database table.

Does anyone know how to connect a wiki to a mysql database table for user authentication?

Comment: `a wiki to a database` If you post the code you have **now** we can nitpick it, but this is waaaaayyy to general to the answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a wiki that already has that functionality. Like Banana Dance (shameless plug!):
http://www.doyoubananadance.com/

If you're stuck using what you currently have, you'll have to simply:
1. Set up a table for users within your MySQL database,
2. Create PHP that will allow users to register/login/edit their accounts.

But since your question is so vague, it's hard to really answer short of doing the programming work for you, which probably won't happen.

Comment: yeah, I realized after some research that this wasn't a very useful question. I should have asked for a wiki with a good security extension. thanks for your help though.